# Event for all WebMethod Requests

Tags: asp.net, webmethod

In our WebApplication we have a lot of [WebMethod] calls. For the purpose of security we want to check if its a logged in user or not (using session). How can I check it without writing code inside all `WebMethods`?

eg.

```
[WebMethod]
public static bool WebMethodCall()
{// check if its a logged in user or not before executing the webmethod
  return true;
}
```

Comment: You can use session there.......

Comment: @dholakiyaankit but see, now I have to write code inside all `[WebMethod]` to check for the valid user

Comment: so what's the problem i don't get you you can check using session in webmethod do you want common method?

Comment: Ya I want an event when any of the `[WebMethod]` is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you this answer by example
i have webservice named common.cs
now

```
   public class Common : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {


     public Common () 

        {
           //here you can check your session so when ever your 
webmethod will be executed this code will call first then your webmethod

        }
//this webmethod will be executed after common
       [WebMethod]
      public static bool WebMethodCall()
         {// check if its a logged in user or not before executing the webmethod
               return true;
         }
[WebMethod]
      public static bool WebMethodCall1()
         {// check if its a logged in user or not before executing the webmethod
               return true;
         }
    }
```

So explaination will be like this 
you have common class named **common** and two webmethod **webmethodcall** and **webmethodcall1**
add your common code in **common** 
I hope this will help you regards...:)

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is to utilize a custom httpModule. However, further readings indicate using SoapExtensions can do the trick. See example:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASMXSoapExtensionToStripOutWhitespaceAndNewLines.aspx